# Udev, scripts and permission

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, udev

Founds lots of other posts with "similar" problems, but none that are actually close to the issue I have.

Raspberry PI Raspian.

My Udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/bash usr/bin/cardin.sh"
```

The cardin.sh in turns call another script (because this one can take long to run - hence cannot be called directly by udev). I output that on tty1 to show on the Pi screen.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "SD CARD DETECTED">/dev/tty1
(/bin/bash /usr/bin/empty-card.sh >/dev/tty1) &
```

This second script then do a few things (some is not shown here for professional confidentiality reason), including parsing a txt file, looking for a date string written in UTC time and displaying them in local time.

```
#!/bin/bash
SD_LOC="/media/sd_card"
CARD_FOLDER="$SD_LOC/st"
DEV="/dev/sda1"
if [ -b $DEV ]; then
shopt -s nullglob   ##to avoid wildcard list being non empty
mount $DEV $SD_LOC
echo "SD-Card Mounted WAIT WAIT WAIT WAIT WAIT WAIT"
DIR_CONTENTS=$(ls -A "$CARD_FOLDER")
if [ -z "$DIR_CONTENTS" ] ; then 
    echo "This is an Empty Card"
else
    echo -e  "List of Folders Found:"
    for FOLDER in "$CARD_FOLDER"/* ; do
        NAME="$(basename "$FOLDER")"
        LOG="$FOLDER/log.txt"
        if [ -r $LOG ] ; then
            START=$(grep "Recording started," "$LOG" | grep -oE '[0-9]{2}-[a-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}[[:space:]][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]')
            STOP=$(grep "Recording stopped," "$LOG" | grep -oE '[0-9]{2}-[a-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}[[:space:]][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]')
            echo  -e "$NAME  --- Started $(date -d "$START UTC")  --- Finished $(date -d "$STOP UTC")"
        else 
            echo "$NAME   ---  No Log File in there"
        fi
    done
    echo -e "\nSD-Card Copying:"
    for FOLDER in "$CARD_FOLDER"/* ; do
        ##[lots of other stuff not relevant to the quesiton]
    done
    echo "SD-Card All - SD Card emptied"
fi
umount $SD_LOC
echo "SD-Card Ummounted - OK TO REMOVE OK TO REMOVE OK TO REMOVE OK TO REMOVE OK TO REMOVE OK TO REMOVE"
else
    echo "SD-Card No SD Card"
fi
```

These two scripts both are owned by root.

My issue is that if I manually call the first script, or the second script, it produces the expected result. I do not need to sudo the call; it work if I do anyway.
But when triggered by Udev, i.e. when inserting the card, then the script does everything (including some cp / mv comands in the not shown section), BUT it does not display the proper dates from the log files, instead displays today's date at 10:00 .

Current debugging status: The Space in my regex was one of the the culprits. I am using now [[:space:]].
The two hyphens are two other culprits - trying to escape them but it does not work. I tried -, \- and even "-" and "\-"
Any other clues?